# Getting Type Expected Error in VB

Tags: vb.net

Please see attached code

```
topThird = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(NewLateBinding.LateGet(Nothing, GetType((System.Math), "Round", New Object() {Operators.DivideObject(totalTitles, CType(3, Integer))}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing))
```

I am getting an error in VS 2008 that says "Type Expected". I am at a loss and cannot figure out what I need to add. I can see from the error something is not correct but I am not sure what. BTW option strict is ON

I can post the whole function if it is needed, please post a comment if this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an error with brakets: you have 8 opening brakets and only 7 closing... maybe there is a superfluous one near GetType.